# How to write JUnit test cases for generic array

Tags: java, junit

How can I write a test case for the below generic method?

```
public <T> T getValueAtIndex(int i) {
    return (T) values[i];
}
```

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: What do you think you could do? Create some instances of classes of your choice, store them in `values`, run the method and do something like `assertEquals` on the result. Since it is generic, you may want to test it with more than one class...

Answer (score 0):

A generic is just a way to reuse code, if they did not exist you would implement (theoretically)

```
public String getValueAtIndex(int i) {
    return (String) values[i];
}

public Integer getValueAtIndex(int i) {
    return (Integer) values[i];
}

public UserEntity getValueAtIndex(int i) {
    return (UserEntity) values[i];
}
```

a method for each type that your function can handle...and if you write a method you have to test it, right? so my suggestion is just to write a test for each interesting specialization. In your case (and, hopefully, in most of the cases) the type specialization doesn't affect the behaviour of the method. Maybe you want to verify that you can access values of array that holds object of multiple types, so test the method on an array which hold a string, an integer and you can access them without any exception